# oop -- mutual dependency between chessboard and its pieces

Tags: scala, oop, dependencies

There have been many similar questions on mutual dependencies, but each leaves me unsure about my own design.

I am writing a chess program to learn Scala. The close relationship between a board and its pieces makes me wonder if a Piece object should contain a reference to the board it belongs to. This was my approach when I wrote a chess program in Java.

However, this means a board is not fully defined until it has its pieces, and vice-versa. This codependency is no problem if the Board instance is a variable you can add pieces to as you build the board, but that goes against immutability.

### Related:

The approach here would seem to suggest defining all the rules of piece movement in the board object:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43681/how-to-avoid-circular-dependencies-between-player-and-world

The highest voted answer here has a similar suggestion:
[Two objects with dependencies for each other. Is that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615868/two-objects-with-dependencies-for-each-other-is-that-bad)

The selected answer for the above link is different -- it moves the mutual dependency from the class definitions to interfaces. I don't understand why that is better.

**The design here mirrors my current approach**:
https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/change-bidirectional-association-to-unidirectional

### My Code:

```
abstract class Piece(val side: Side.Value, val row: Int, val col: Int){
  val piece_type: PieceType.Value //isInstanceOf() could accomplish the same
  def possible_moves(board: Board): List[Move]
}

class Board (val pieces: Array[Array[Piece]]){
  def this(){
    this(DefaultBoard.setup) //An object which builds the starting board
  } 
}
```

Having to pass as a parameter the board to which a piece belongs would work, but it feels wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't actually looked at your code much, but just as a general suggestion, when you have a mutual dependency, there are often two reasons for that: a) the two objects really should be one object, b) the two objects should really be *three* objects, with the mutual dependency extracted into a single third object. Of course, it's entirely possible that there *is* a genuine mutual dependency. In that case, you need either a more widely scoped bigger re-design or accept that this mutual dependency is an intrinsic part of your domain model.

Comment: A typical pain-point with passing a "context"-like entity (such as the board in your code) into various methods, is when those methods then call further methods that need that "context", etc. In Scala, this can be alleviated by marking that argument as `implicit` in all such methods. Then if an implicit "context" instance is declared / made available at the "top" of a computation process, it will be passed on down as required without having to be explicitly mentioned at any call sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some liberty to redesign your classes.

The first thing I noticed: Your `Piece` isn't really a piece.
Say there is a white bishop on the top left field.
If I move it to the top right field, does it become a different piece? -
Obviously not.
Therefore, the position of a piece on the board is not part of its identity.

So I would refactor the class `Piece` to this:

```
trait Piece {
  def side:Side.Value
  def piece_type:PieceType.Value
}
```

(I used a trait instead of an abstract class here so that I leave it open for the implementor how to implement those two methods.)

The information that was lost in the process should be put in a different type:

```
case class PiecePlacement(piece:Piece, row:Int, col:Int) {
  def possible_moves(board:Board):Seq[Move] = ??? // Why enfore a list here?
}
```

Now we can define a board like this:

```
case class Board(pieces:IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Piece]] = DefaultBoard.setup)
```

(Notice how I replaced the auxiliary constructor with a default parameter value, and also used the immutable `IndexedSeq` instead of the mutable `Array`.)

If you now would like to also have a dependency between the placement of the piece and the board, you can do it like this:

1. Add the board to `PiecePlacement`:

`case class PiecePlacement(piece:Piece, row:Int, col:Int, board:Board) {...}`

2. Make the board create the placement instances:

`case class Board(...) {
  def place(piece:Piece, row:Int, col:Int):(Board,PiecePlacement) = ???
}`

Note that the return value of `place` returns not only the new `PiecePlacement` instance, but also the new `Board` instance, because we want to work with immutable instances.

Now, if you look at this, the question should be raised why `place` even returns the `PiecePlacement`. What benefit would the caller ever have of it? It's pretty much just board-internal information. Therefore, you would probably refactor the `place` method such that it returns only the new `Board`. Then, you could consequently go without the `Placement` type altogether and thereby eliminate the mutual dependency.

Another thing that you might want to notice is that the `place` method cannot be implemented. The returned `Board` must be a new instance, but the returned `PiecePlacement` must contain the new `Board` instance. Since the new `Board` instance also contains the `PiecePlacement` instance, it can never be created in a completely immutable way.

So I would really follow the advice of @JörgWMittag and get rid of the mutual references. Start defining traits for your boards and pieces, and include only the absolute minimum of necessary information. For example:

```
trait Board {
  def at(row:Int, col:Int):Option[Piece]
  def withPieceAt(piece:Piece, row:Int, col:Int):Board
  def withoutPieceAt(row:Int, col:Int):Board
}

sealed trait Move
case class Movement(startRow:Int, startCol:Int, endRow:Int, endCol:Int) extends Move
case class Capture(startRow:Int, startCol:Int, endRow:Int, endCol:Int) extends Move

sealed trait PieceType {
  def possibleMoves(board:Board, row:Int, col:Int):Seq[Move]
}
object Pawn extends PieceType {...}
object Bishop extends PieceType {...}

sealed trait Piece {
  def side:Side.Value
  def pieceType:PieceType
}
case class WhitePiece(pieceType:PieceType) {
  def side:Side.White
}
case class BlackPiece(pieceType:PieceType) {
  def side:Side.Black
}
```

Now you can start writing code that uses those traits to reason about potential moves etc.
Also, you can write the classes that implement those traits.
You can start off with a straightforward implementation, and then optimize as necessary.

For example: Every board position has only 13 possible states. One per chess piece type, times two for the two sides, plus one for the empty state. Those states are very enumerable, so you might optimize by enumerating them.

Another potential optimization: Since a board position requires only 4 bits for modelling it, one whole row of the board fits into an `Int` variable when encoded. Therefore, the whole board state can be represented as just eight `Int`s, or even as four `Long`s. This optimization would trade off performance (bit shifting) in favor of memory usage. So this optimization would be better for an algorithm that generates a huge number of `Board` instances and gets in danger of getting an `OutOfMemoryError`.

By modelling the board and the pieces as traits rather than classes, you can easily exchange the implementations, play around with them, and see which implementation works best for you use case - without having to change a bit of the algorithms that make use of the boards and pieces.

Bottom line: Introduce things like methods and variables only when needed.
Every line of code that you don't write is a line of code that cannot contain a bug.
Don't worry about mutual dependencies between objects when they are not strictly necessary. And in the case of a chess board model, they definitely are not necessary.

Focus on simplicity first. Every single method, class and parameter should justify its existence.

For example, in the model that I proposed, there is always two parameters for a position: `row` and `col`. Since there are only 64 possible positions, I would argue to make a `Position` type. It can even be an `AnyVal` type that would be compiled as an `Int`, for example. Then, you wouldn't need the nested structure to store the board. You can just store 64 board placement information objects, that's it.

Introduce only the minimum necessary, and extend when needed. In the extreme case, start with empty traits and add methods only when you really cannot go on without them. While you're at it, write unit tests for every single method. That way, you should get to a good, clean and reusable solution. The key of reusability is: Avoid features as much as you can. Every single feature that you introduce restricts versatility. Put in just what is strictly required.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. It really improved my understanding of traits.

Follow up question: to extract data from a board representation that uses 8 integers, I would define the extraction function as a method in the class implementing the Board trait, right? And that extraction would be used by that class's implementation of "at", "withPieceAt", etc?